# Backreferences in PHP preg_replace() is instable?

Tags: php, html, regex

In order to escape double or single quotes, I used the regex back references:

```
$strVal = '<div class="xclassname">Contents</div>';
$strVal = preg_replace("/([\"\'])/", "\\\\1", $strVal);
```

This usually gave me this string (since years):

```
"<div class=\"xclassname\">Contents</div>"
```

with the double quotes correctly escaped in C++ style.

But today my PHP 5.5.3 gives me this result:

```
"<div class=\1xclassname\1>Contents</div>"
```

with the double quotes replaced by the bad \1 string.

Now I must use this:

```
$strVal = preg_replace("/([\"\'])/", "\\\\\${1}", $strVal);
```

preg_replace() is instable in my Windows 7 OS, sometimes it gives one result, other days it gives another ?

Have you encountered this situation please, and why ?

ADDED:

I've forgotten that we've updated PHP 5.3 to PHP5.5.3 some weeks before, preg_repace() is unstable according to PHP versions, not in function of date-time:

```
preg_replace("/([\"\'])/", "\\\\1", $strVal); // is OK for PHP5.3.x, but
preg_replace("/([\"\'])/", "\\\\1", $strVal); // is bad for PHP5.5.x.
preg_replace("/([\"\'])/", "\\\\\${1}", $strVal); // is good for PHP5.5.x.
```

That's it, I have no multiple versions of PHP, can you confirm ?

Comment: Simplest/best answer: Don't use regexes to manipulation html/xml. preg_replace is NOT unstable. it does exactly what it should. If you get different results, then something is changing your system configuration behind your back - e.g. multiple PHP versions installed.

Comment: `'\\\$1'` would probably be a simpler replacement FYI

Comment: Also, backreferences tend to be `\#` in the regex, then `$#` in the replace (for PHP funcs) - where `#` is the group number

Comment: Why are you trying to manually escape quotes?  What are you doing with this string?  It's usually a bad idea to create your own data escape methods, especially when PHP/your database has ones built-in.

Comment: @Marc B, "Don't use regexes to manipulation html/xml" ? I don't understand why ? Is it not just the function of preg_* family routines ?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat, with the escaped quotes in HTML string, I can inject it by AJAX contents as .InnerHTML, and can be manipulated easily by JavaScript without error.

Comment: @jacouh: Why would unescaped quotes cause an error in innerHTML?  Have you tried something like `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP, yes your single quoted '\\\$1' works very well. If one replaces with "\\\$1", it does not more work.

Comment: @jacouh That's because when using double quotes (`"`) PHP will parse the string, giving the `$` a special meaning (start of local variable), therefore requiring that to also be escaped. When using single quotes/apostrophes (`'`) only the backslash needs escaping.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat, I store HTML string in PHP cache code by querying MySQL db beforehand, and will be fetched as AJAX contents to some page later. So in PHP code, HTML attribute specified by double quotes must be anti-slashed in PHP syntax. It's in effect not because of .InnerHTML constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_*` functions work better with `$1` in the first place, and it is recommended you use them. That said, why not just use [`addslashes`](http://php.net/addslashes) for this task?

Comment: "$1 in the first place", this is not clear, could you please give an example ?

Comment: After test, addslashes() does really a good job, preg_replace() also.